# Consequences of Zeeman's conjecture

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, simplicial-complexes, conjectures

Recall the Zeeman's conjecture: if $K$ is a contractible polyhedron of dimension 2, then $K\times I$ has a collapsible subdivision.

Zeeman showed that this implies the Poincaré conjecture in dimension 3 (which is [equivalent to a restricted version of Zeeman's conjecture](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383%2883%2990017-4)). It also implies the Andrews-Curtis conjecture (again, there is [equivalence of a restricted version](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00969470)). In advertising Zeeman's conjecture these seem to be the two main points. (For an example of such an 'advertisement' see [these notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~kupers/zeemansconjecture.pdf).)

**Question 1:** What are some other interesting consequences of Zeeman's conjecture being (or not being) true?

I have seen an opinion that the conjecture is generally believed to be false.

**Question 2:** What are the reasons to believe it is false?

Comment: Regarding Question 2: there seem to be unpublished counterexamples to the Andrews-Curtis conjecture: http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/kar/Past%20classes.html

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an accurate summary of what you find on that web page. There is a non-specific reference to an unpublished result of Bridson, and a reference to a published paper of Burns-Macedonska giving potential counterexamples.